# How can I perform a check on all 'th' values using JQUERY?

Tags: html, jquery

I have create a function that adds rows based on value of a dropdown list.
The user selects a project, clicks the Add button, and a row with the name of the project and a set of cells are added to the table.
The name of the project is inside a 'th' tag.

I want to add a condition that the add button does not add a row if the project has already been added:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var i = 1
  var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');

  //Then if no tbody just select your table
  var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');

/*  table.find('th').each(function(){
    if (th.value = projval)
    alert("project already in");
  });*/

  $('#addrow').click(function() {
    //Add row
  var projval = $('#projSel').val();

  $('#myTable > tbody > tr > th').each(function(index, th) {
       console.log(index);
       // if($("th").eq(index).attr('id') = projval) {
       //    alert("Exist");
       // }
  });

        table.append('<tr><th scope="row" id="' + projval + '">' + projval + '</th>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inMon' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inTue' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inWed' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inThu' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inFri' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inSat' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="inSun' + i + '" placeholder="00:00"></td>\
  <td><button name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</td></tr>');
        i++;
      })
});
```

projVal variable is the value selected from the dropdown list
myTable is the ID of the table.

I cannot figure how to write the if condition so that the index retrieves the value of 'th' ID and compares it to the already exisiting 'th' added by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the below code:

```js
$('#addrow').click(function () {
    var projval = $('#projSel').val();
    var projectAdded = $('tr>th[scope=row][id="' + projval + '"]', table).length > 0;
    if (projectAdded) {
        alert('project already in');
        return false;
    }
    // ... Add Row Code
    i++;
})
```